# Single Domain with different paths route to different nginx servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Usecase:
I have different aws servers like server1,server2,server3 and infront an AWS ALB
Single Domain called example.com

```
example.com/s1 should route to server1
example.com/s2 should route to server2
example.com/s3 should route to server3
```

My config files inside /etc/nginx/sites-available for server1,2,3

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;

    server_name example.com albdns.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /login {
        proxy_pass https://publicipofserver1/;
    }
    location /s1 {
        return 301 https://publicipofserver1/;
    }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        #root /var/www/example.com/html;
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com albdns.com;

        #location / {
        #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #}
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}
```

**Issue1:**

With this when I use the domain name It can redirect say

```
example.com/s1 -> publicipofs1/login
```

But not working for s2 and s3 ..it says

**example.com redirected you too many times.**

**Is this correct way of configuration?**

**Issue 2:**

**Anyway to not expose the publicip when this redirect?**
When I use albdns/s1 in browser it changes to s1ipaddress in url tab
like albnds/s1 -> x.x.x.x/s1

Comment: ALB can split your income by path and send the traffic for each server. Why nginx?

Comment: @Lamanus Sort of requirement...server 1 and 2 are behind alb while server 3 is separate nginx web instance